# RestTemplate GET with parameteres with Spring Boot Controller

Tags: rest, api, spring-boot, kotlin, resttemplate

I'm creating a microservice that recieves data from Rest Template requests to API. I run microservice at localhost:8080 and API at localhost:13001 and test it with Postman. Test method returns String. And there is an issue when request has parameteres. With code below I always get "404 Not Found". But when API controller don't have any parameteres - method works. Can't solve this problem.

Sequence:

1) Postman (GET http://localhost:8080/test)

2) Microservice Controller (Rest Template exchange) --> code below

```
@RequestMapping(
        method                          = [RequestMethod.GET],
        produces                        = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE],
        path                            = ["/test"],
        params                          = ["workspace_id"]
        )
@ResponseBody
fun test(
        authentication                  : OAuth2Authentication,
        @RequestParam(value             = "workspace_id")
        workspaceId                     : UUID
)                                       : String
{
    return serviceDashboard.get(authentication, workspaceId)
}
```

3) Rest Template (GET http://localhost:13001/test?workspace_id=......) --> code below

```
    @Autowired
lateinit var restTemplate               : RestTemplate

    override fun get(
        authentication                  : OAuth2Authentication,
        workspaceId                     : UUID
)                                       : String
{
    //Header
    val token                           = (authentication.details as OAuth2AuthenticationDetails).tokenValue
    val headers                         = HttpHeaders()
    headers.setBearerAuth(token)
    val entity                          = HttpEntity<Any>(headers)
    //Parameters
    val params                          = HashMap<String, UUID>()
    params["workspace_id"]              = workspaceId
    //URI
    val endpoint                        = URI.create("http://localhost:13001/test")

    return restTemplate.exchange(endpoint.toString(), HttpMethod.GET, entity, String::class.java, params).body!!
}
```

4) API Controller (return data) --> code below

----------- Non-working version ----------------

```
@GetMapping(
        produces                        = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE],
        params                          = ["workspace_id"],
        path                            = ["/test"])
@ResponseBody
fun test(
        @RequestParam(value = "workspace_id")
        workspaceId                     : UUID
)                                       : String
{
    if ( workspaceId.toString() == "650a539a-0356-467e-a0d0-71d472c41aae") return "It works"
    else return "It doesn't work"
}
```

----------- Working version ----------------

```
@GetMapping(
        produces                        = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE]
        path                            = ["/test"])
@ResponseBody
fun test()                              : String
{
    return "It works"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried giving @RequestParam (and/or @PathVariable) params to the function _without_ using the ‘params’ annotation param?  (That's what we've always done.)

Comment: Yes, like this: @GetMapping(value="/test/{workspace_id}" and then @PathVariable

Answer (score 0):

What is the annotation you are using at Class level.
You need to use @RestController.